# Why inverse Lorentz transform gives different result than regular Lorentz transform?

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

Suppose there is a frame O' that moves with speed $\frac{\sqrt{3} c}{2}$ relative to frame O. I wish to find out how much time has passed on frame O' $t'$ when $t=50$. Clocks from frames O and O' are synchronized at the start $t=t'=0$.

There are two transformation formulas I can use:

$$t' = \gamma \left( t - \frac{v x}{c^2} \right)$$

and

$$t = \gamma \left( t' + \frac{v x'}{c^2} \right)$$

But both of them gives different answers. The second one is easy to solve. I set $x'=0$ and I get $t=\gamma t'$ which is the expected result. But if I try the first one,

$$t' = \gamma \left( t - \frac{v x}{c^2} \right) = \gamma \left( t - \frac{v}{c^2} \gamma (x'+vt') \right)$$

$$\left(1+\gamma^2\frac{v^2}{c^2}\right)t'=\gamma t$$

which will give the different answer than $t=\gamma t'$. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Hint: $\gamma = (1 - (v/c)^2)^{-1/2}$.

Answer (score 0):

To pass from the equation (direct tranformation): $x'=\gamma(x-vt)$ to equation: $t'=\gamma\left(t-\frac{vx}{c^{2}}\right)$, we pose $x=ct,\;\;$ i.e.
$$t'=\gamma\left(t-\frac{vt}{c}\right)$$
which gives: $$t'=\gamma\left(1-\frac{v}{c}\right)t=\sqrt\frac{{1-\beta}}{1+\beta}\,t\;\;\;\;(1)$$ where $\beta=\frac{v}{c}$

the inverse transformation gives :$$t=\gamma\left(1+\frac{v}{c}\right)t'=\sqrt\frac{{1+\beta}}{1-\beta}\,t'\;\;\;\;(2)$$
if we replace (1) in (2) , we find $$t=t$$
Remark :

To take the equation $t'=\gamma(t-vx/c²)$ and to make the difference $dt'=\gamma(dt-vdx/c²)$ and to say that if $\;dx=0\;$, $dt'= \gamma dt\;$ does not have any physical sense without evoking the general transformation, because to obtain this equation, one started from the equation $x'=\gamma(x-vt) $ and by posing $$x=ct$$ if $dx=0$ $\;;dt=0$.

PS: In the general case (x'=0):

- Lorentz vector transformations (LVT) are
  $$\begin{cases}t'=\gamma (t- \frac {\vec{r}. v\vec {n}  }{c^{2}})\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(a)\\\\ \vec{r'} =\vec {r} +(\gamma -1)(\vec {r} \cdot \vec {n} )\vec {n} -\gamma tv \vec {n}\;\;\;\;\;\;(b)\tag{1.1}\end{cases}$$

where
$$\begin{cases} \vec{r} =\vec {r} _{\perp }+\vec{r} _{||}\\  \vec {r'} =\vec{r'} _{\perp }+\vec{r'}_{||}\\ \gamma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^{2}}{c^{2}}}}\end{cases}$$

I) We suppose that $\vec{r}$ is orthogonal to the axis of direction vector   $\vec{n}=\frac{\vec{v}}{v}$, equation (a) becomes:
$$t'=\gamma[t-v(\vec{r}_{\perp}+\vec{r}_{||}).\vec{n}]$$
by supposing the projection of $\vec{r}$ on the axis of direction vector $\vec{n}$ is $\vec{r}_{||}=\vec{0}$ et $\vec{r}_{\perp}.\vec{n}=0$, ce qui donne
$$t'=\gamma t\tag{1.2}$$
and equation (b) is written
$$\vec{r'}=\vec{r'}_{\perp} + \vec{r'}_{||}=\vec{r}_{\perp}+ \vec{r}_{||}+(\gamma -1)[(\vec{r}_{\perp}+\vec{r}_{||}).\vec{n}] \vec{n}-\gamma vt\vec{n}$$

with:$$\vec{r'}_{\perp}= \vec{r}_ {\perp}$$

which results with (1.2)
$$\vec{r'}_{||}= - vt'\vec{n}$$

we have  $$\vec{r'}=\vec{r'}_{\perp}+ \vec{r'}_{||}=\vec{r}_{\perp}+ \vec{r'}_{||}$$
$$r'^{2}=r^{2}+r'^{2}_{||}=r^{2}+v^{2}t'^{2}$$

for light, the previous equation gives

$$c^{2}t'^{2}=c^{2}t^{2}+v^{2}t'^{2}$$
$$t'=\gamma t $$
The two equations of the system (1.1) give the same result.

II) In the inverse Lorentz vector transformation 
$$\begin{cases}t=\gamma (t'+ \frac {\vec{r'}.v\vec {n}  }{c^{2}})\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(a')\\\\ \vec{r} =\vec {r'} +(\gamma -1)(\vec {r'} \cdot \vec {n} )\vec {n} +\gamma t'v \vec {n}\;\;\;\;\;\;(b')\tag{1.3}\end{cases}$$

we assume that $\vec{r'}$ is orthogonal to the axis of direction vector  $\vec{n}=\frac{\vec{v}}{v}$,
we have
[\begin{cases}t=\gamma[t'+v(\vec{r'}_{\perp}+\vec{r'}_{||}).\vec{n}]\\\\ \vec{r}=\vec{r}_{\perp}+ \vec{r}_{||}=\vec{r'}_{\perp}+ \vec{r'}_{||}+(\gamma -1)[(\vec{r'}_{\perp}+\vec{r'}_{||}).\vec{n}] \vec{n}+\gamma vt'\vec{n}\end{cases}]

by supposing the projection ofe $\vec{r'}$ on the axis of direction vector  $\vec{n}$ is $\vec{r'}_{||}=\vec{0}$ et $\vec{r'}_{\perp}.\vec{n}=0$\

the equation (a') becomes  $$t=\gamma t'\tag{1.4}$$

the relation (b') with : $\vec{r'}_{\perp}= \vec{r}_ {\perp}$ and (1.4) is equivalent to $\vec{r}_{||}= vt\vec{n}$

and $$\vec{r}=\vec{r}_{\perp}+ \vec{r}_{||}=\vec{r'}_{\perp}+ \vec{r}_{||}$$

of norm

$$r^{2}=r'^{2}+r_{||}^{2}=r'^{2}+v^{2}t^{2}$$

for the light, we have

$$ c^{2}t^{2}=c^{2}t'^{2}+v^{2}t^{2}$$
i.e
$$t=\gamma t'$$
which is only the equation (1.4).

We see that if the reference frame of the observer O' in $\mathcal{R'}$ must remain orthogonal to the axis of the point where the event takes place (x'=0), it is necessary to consider that it is the reference frame $\mathcal{R}$ which is in motion with respect to $\mathcal{R'}$ , that is to say to change the notations $t'\equiv t$ and $v\equiv-v$ in the inverse transformations and that is the equivalence of the inertial reference frames. (O' is in motion with respect to O (O'/O) or it is O/O').

"No shortening no pretending" Alexander Grothendieck